# Multi-Portal CMS for MONO

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, mono

I am searching for a CMS system which is based on ASP.net (preferable MVC 3) which runs also under MONO on a linux system AND is able to host multiple portals so I can host 2+ pages with one installation and share some resources and has the basic stuff like articles, image gallery and so on already built in, but can also be extended using C#.

Similar Questions where already asked years ago without suitable answers, but many things have changed since then.

I already checked out Kooboo 3 (basic system looks nice, but there are nearly no modules like image gallery) and mojoPortal (no multi protal and the backend did have layout problems with chrome).

Does anyone know something which would fit my needs (better)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems there is nothing around which fits my needs I am think ybout switching my server to windows so I can use more prodicts around there.
At the moment I am looking into Composite C1 and Umbraco.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but checkout kooboo cms - [KoobooCMS](http://kooboo.com)

Pretty extensible and I like how they don't push a heavy CMS paradigm on you.  There is a little learning curve but to be honest, I had an easier time getting a site done with this than Umbraco or Orchard.  Plus it's plugable on the backend.

Kooboo 4 is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

[Orchard](http://orchardproject.net/) supports [multi tenancy](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-multi-tenant-orchard-site) and is built upon ASP.Net MVC. I haven't tried it yet, but [according to the site](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Running-Orchard-on-Mono) it can run on mono.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but thats not really what I want, as the multi tenancy only shares the binaries, but not the resources of each tenant...

Comment: Having experience with managing large shared multi-tenancy resources, I would suggest having a copy of the resource vs shared.  You can run into issue deploying shared resource that can break other tenant sites.  Of course, there's always exception case where you want to share if the other tenants are just business unit of a bigger tenant.